# useEffect running infinitely and my daily limit on firebase reached within 2hours

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

i have made a CRUD app using firebase and react mostly on my own,
`

```
  const userEmail = localStorage.getItem("email");
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [rowToEdit, setRowToEdit] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    console.log("no. of getData calls");
    const docRef = collection(db, "bunkManager",`${userEmail}`,"course");
    const dataDB = await getDocs(docRef);
    const allData = dataDB.docs.map(val => ({course:val.id, ...val.data(),}));
    setRows(allData);
  };

    useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    console.log("useEffect");
  },[]);

  const handleSubmit = async (newRow) => {
    await setDoc(doc(db,"bunkManager", userEmail, "course",newRow.course), {
      bunkedHours: newRow.bunkedHours,
      totalHours: newRow.totalHours
    });
  };

  const handleEditRow = (index) => {
    setRowToEdit(index);

    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDeleteRow = async (course) => {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "bunkManager", userEmail, "course",course));
  };

  return (
    <>
    <Table rows={rows} deleteRow={handleDeleteRow} editRow={handleEditRow}/>
    <button className='submit_btn' onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>Add Course</button>
    {modalOpen && <Modal closeModal={() => {setModalOpen(false); setRowToEdit(null);}} onSubmit={handleSubmit} defaultValue={rowToEdit !== null && rows[rowToEdit]}/>}
    </>
  )
}`
```

the console log inside useEffect is being infinitely called, i didnt notice it untill my app stopped working due to firebase limit on read.

im using useEffect to get data whenever theres an update to the table, but if its gonna infinitely call getData(); i cant have this app running in long time,

i tried my best to find answers but i couldnt :(, im sorry if there are multiple similar posts with similar problem

Comment: Place code as text instead of image

Comment: my bad  about the [rows] in useEffect part, i didnt see, but i remember trying without anything and with empty brackets [], but for some reason when it executes one time, the getData(); doesnt get me data. im sorry i cant try again since firebase has limited me, i will surely update tomr

Comment: Please read my answer(below), it should be `[userEmail]` or even better I think `[db, userEmail]`. When you use empty `[]` it expected to execute only once

Comment: my solution: made a new useState and changed it value for every function the website executes and passed it to the 2nd parameter in useEffect, now it works as intended.
Thank you so much guys, i finally understand how useState, useEffect works for most part and i feel confident using them now!

Answer (score 2):

getData sets rows.
When rows is set useEffect triggers.
useEffect calls getData.
getData sets rows.
Etc. etc.

You've set up an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

You have given the state `rows` as dependency array to `useEffect`, and in the `useEffect` you are calling the API with `getData` and then call `setRows` which changes `row` state again and makes the `useEffect` runs indefinitely. If you want to run `useEffect` only once, do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => { getData(); }, []);
```

I hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You add `rows` in the dependencies array of the `useEffect` but in the `useEffect` you also make changes to `rows` by calling `setRows(allData)`. This creates an infinite loop since the dependencies of the `useEffect` hook always change at every render.

Answer (score 1):

Second argument to `useEffect` should be `[userEmail]` instead of `[rows]`, You can read more about it [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect). To make it even better you can use `[db, userEmail]` and code depends on those two variables as arguments
The issue is that you have placed destination variable instead of the dependencies that results into infinite loop